# why is \$|V_C|=90\$, not \$70\$? series RLC circuit

Tags: voltage, ac, homework

If \$|V_S|=100V\$,\$|V_R|=60V\$,and \$|V_L|=10V\$,then what is \$|V_C|\$ ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkFGyX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My solution

\$100=\sqrt{60^2+(10-V_C)^2}\$,so \$(10-V_C)^2=80^2\$,so \$(10-V_C)=80\$,now we can know\$V_C=10-80=-70V\$,so \$|V_C|=70\$

However ,the book tells me the answer is \$|V_C|=90\$ ,indeed if i replace 
\$|V_C|\$ with \$90\$ into \$(10-V_C)^2=80^2\$,the formula does hold,so i want to ask why is \$|V_C|=90\$,not \$70\$,what is the mistake about my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$V_s = \sqrt{V_R^2 + (V_L - V_c)^2}$$
$$(10-V_C)^2 = 80^2$$
This is a quadratic equation, and has the roots -70 and 90. We can ignore the negative value, which gives us the value of \$V_c\$ as \$90 \space V\$.

Comment: why can we ignore the negative one?

Comment: If \$V_C\$ is negative, then the current in the capacitor will lead the voltage, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage across the capacitor and the voltage across the inductor are 180 degrees apart hence when you calculated the voltage across both (\$X_L + X_C\$) to be 80 volts, that is the net voltage and, the capacitor voltage is in fact \$V_C\$ is 90 volts.

<sub>If voltages are 180 degrees apart and are in series then the net effect is one of subtraction.</sub>

**Rough simulation:**

[image]

Peak capacitor voltage (blue) is about 90 volts and peak inductor voltage (red) is about 10 volts but, importantly, they are anti-phase and their net effect, in terms of voltage is subtractive.

**Circuit simulated:**

[image]

Comment: a little bit don't understand what you said,can you provide the formula about the modification of my formula? i think that i can understand what you said easier

Comment: Hopefully, better still, I've done a rough simulation that shows how the two voltages are antiphase.

Comment: so in fact ,my formula is not wrong,you just tell me why we should choose the positive one,not negative one?

Comment: You calculated 80 volts as the net voltage across the capacitor and inductor together so, if we know that the inductor voltage is 10 volts AND we know it subtracts from the capacitor voltage then \$V_C - \text{ 10 volts} = \text{ 80 volts}\$. Hence \$V_C\$ = 90 volts.

Comment: so my formula should be modified from \$100=\sqrt{60^2+(10-V_C)^2}\$ to \$100=\sqrt{60^2+(-10+V_C)^2}\$?

Comment: You can do that or, just recognize that the solution has two roots (and pick the correct one) OR, just recognize that if the net voltage is 80 volts and the inductor voltage is 10 volts then the capacitor voltage MUST BE 90 volts - they share the same current and their impedances are 180 degrees apart.